# Multiple points/colors gradient on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, gradient

I would like to fill a shape on a html5 canvas with a gradient created from several differents colors at different positions, like on [this picture](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/gradient_inverse.gif).

Do you have any ideas on how I could do that?

Comment: A little more information could be good. You need it to be animated o change its size? Will Colors and spots be generated at runtime? What have you try? For what will it be used, background?

Comment: I'm drawing a voronoi diagram where each cell as a different color, and I want the transition between each cell to be "smooth".

It does not need to be animated. 
Colors and spots are generated at runtime.
Ideally if I could use it like a radial or linear gradient that would be perfect !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching a little I have found this example from Mozilla Development Network

```
function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

    var radgrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,1,0,0,150);
    radgrad.addColorStop(0, '#A7D30C');
    radgrad.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(1,159,98,0)');

    var radgrad2 = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,150,1,0,150,150);
    radgrad2.addColorStop(0, '#FF5F98');
    radgrad2.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255,1,136,0)');

    var radgrad3 = ctx.createRadialGradient(150,0,1,150,0,150);
    radgrad3.addColorStop(0, '#00C9FF');
    radgrad3.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,201,255,0)');

    var radgrad4 = ctx.createRadialGradient(150,150,1,150,150,150);
    radgrad4.addColorStop(0, '#F4F201');
    radgrad4.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(228,199,0,0)');

    ctx.fillStyle = radgrad4;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,150);
    ctx.fillStyle = radgrad3;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,150);
    ctx.fillStyle = radgrad2;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,150);
    ctx.fillStyle = radgrad;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,150);
}
```

Based int this, you could draw each cell as a radial gradient and use a total transparent color as its final step so it blend better with other cells.

Without it, I think that you will need to calculate each pixel color based on how far from each cell they are.

Normally if when you make a voronoi texture, you divide the surface in a mesh and then assign a color to each vertex, then you interpolate the color of a pixel with the distance to the vertext that form its cell.

Also see http://www.raymondhill.net/voronoi/rhill-voronoi.html for an implementation of real voronoi in html5. It's open source and licensed under The MIT License, so you can use it.

Comment: yes "stacking" multiple radial gradient (where the final color is totally transparent) should do the trick.

Comment: I don't know you need, but get in mind that this isn't how you paint a voronoid, it's a way to fake an image that is similar to a voronoid but with less effort. Also, if you think this answer your question, I will be pleased to be selected as accepted (until a new and better answer appear) ;).

Comment: Yes, this is a workaround. I'm also afraid the performance will be poor if there is a lot of cells. Per pixel interpolation is probably better, but more complex to implement.
I have edited your example (see my original post) to have a similar result as the one in the picture.
Answer accepted :)

Comment: You shouldn't add the answer to the question, if you wanna show the answer with the exact result, you can edit the example of my answer.

Comment: the "rhill-voronoi" is the implementation that i'm currently using ! It works great, I just need to colorize the result with the gradient now.
I have edited your answer and my question.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a principle of multiplying (not summing) all the possible two color linear gradients that your initial points can produce. Check my example:
https://codepen.io/tculda/pen/pogwpOw

```
function getProjectionDistance(a, b, c){
    const k2 = b.x*b.x - b.x*a.x + b.y*b.y -b.y*a.y;
    const k1 = a.x*a.x - b.x*a.x + a.y*a.y -b.y*a.y;
    const ab2 = (a.x - b.x)*(a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y);
    const kcom = (c.x*(a.x - b.x) + c.y*(a.y-b.y));
    const d1 = (k1 - kcom) / ab2;
    const d2 = (k2 + kcom) / ab2;
    return {d1, d2};
}

function limit01(value){
    if(value < 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(value > 1){
        return 1;
    }
    return value;
}
function paddingleft0(v, v_length){
    while( v.length < v_length){
        v = '0' + v;
    }
    return v;
}

function getWeightedColorMix(points, ratios){
    let r = 0;
    let g = 0;
    let b = 0;
    for( [ind, point] of points.entries()){
        r += Math.round(parseInt(point.c.substring(1,3), 16) * ratios[ind]);
        g += Math.round(parseInt(point.c.substring(3,5), 16) * ratios[ind]);
        b += Math.round(parseInt(point.c.substring(5,7), 16) * ratios[ind]);
    }
        
    let result = '#' + paddingleft0(r.toString(16),2) + paddingleft0(g.toString(16),2) + paddingleft0(b.toString(16),2);

    return result;
}

/**
 * Given some points with color attached, calculate the color for a new point
 * @param  p The new point position {x: number, y: number}
 * @param  points The array of given colored points [{x: nember, y: number, c: hexColor}]
 * @return hex color string -- The weighted color mix
 */
function getGeometricColorMix( p, points ){
    let colorRatios = new Array(points.length);
    colorRatios.fill(1);
    for ( [ind1, point1] of points.entries()){
        for ( [ind2, point2] of points.entries()){
            if( ind1 != ind2){
                d  = getProjectionDistance(point1, point2, p);
                colorRatios[ind1] *= limit01(d.d2);
            }
        }

    }
      let totalRatiosSum = 0;
      colorRatios.forEach(c => totalRatiosSum += c);
      colorRatios.forEach((c,i) => colorRatios[i] /= totalRatiosSum);
    c = getWeightedColorMix(points, colorRatios);
    return c;
}

let points = [
    {x:10, y:10, c:"#FF0000"},
    {x:70, y:150, c:"#FFFF00"},
    {x:224, y:300, c:"#00FF00"},
    {x:121, y:100, c:"#00FFFF"},
    {x:160, y:10, c:"#FF00FF"},
]; // these are the starting points for drawing the gradient


var canv = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
let xcs = points.map( p => p.x);
let ycs = points.map( p => p.y);
let xmin = Math.min(...xcs);
let xmax = Math.max(...xcs);
let ymin = Math.min(...ycs);
let ymax = Math.max(...ycs);
let x, y;
let mixColor;

// iterate all the pixels between the given points
for( x = xmin; x < xmax; x++ ){
    for( y = ymin; y < ymax; y++ ){
        mixColor = getGeometricColorMix({x:x, y:y}, points);
        ctx.fillStyle = mixColor;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you're technically doing a weighted sum of the individual gradients, with each gradient going from full to zero opacity between the two points, right? Your code looks cool (result does too), I'll see and learn how it works in detail. I wonder if there is some more efficient way of getting similar results seeing as your code is O(n^2) per pixel with n being the number of points. Thanks

Comment: I converted your code to Java. Pretty optimized too. https://code.botcompany.de/1034870