# js canvas - efficient multi point gradient

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to display a multipoint gradient in a canvas. This multipoint gradient uses many (thousands of) points. It's supposed to generate a 213x144 Image. This process should take less than 3 seconds.

The points of the graident are given like this:

```js
const points = [
 {value: [255, 0, 0], x: 10, y: 10},
 {value: [120, 0, 60], x: 34, y: 16},
 {value: [16, 230, 1], x: 120, y: 112}
];
```

The points are always at the exact position of a pixel.

I tried to solve the explained problem using CPU calculation:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const size = {width: 213, height: 144, len: 30672‬};

for (let i = 0; i < size.len; i++) {
    const x = i % size.width;
    const y = (i - x) / size.width;

    let totalweight = 0;

    let pixelcolor = [[0, 0, 0], false];

    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        if (x === points[i].x && y === points[i].y) {
            pixelcolor = [points[i].value, true];
            break;
        }
        const weight = 0.05 ** (Math.sqrt((x - points[i].x) ** 2 + (y - points[i].y) ** 2));
        totalweight += weight;

        pixelcolor[0][0] += points[i].value[0] * weight;
        pixelcolor[0][1] += points[i].value[1] * weight;
        pixelcolor[0][2] += points[i].value[2] * weight;
    }

    if(!pixelcolor[1]) {
        pixelcolor[0][0] = pixelcolor[0][0] / totalweight;
        pixelcolor[0][1] = pixelcolor[0][1] / totalweight;
        pixelcolor[0][2] = pixelcolor[0][2] / totalweight;

    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${pixelcolor[0][0]}, ${pixelcolor[0][1]}, ${pixelcolor[0][2]}, 1)`;
    ctx.rect(x, y, 1, 1);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

This unfortunately takes multiple seconds (when tested with 6000 points), even when I made it multithreaded (won't provide code as it's unneccessary and too long).

I searched for a hardware accelerated solution, but the only one if found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356012/multiple-points-colors-gradient-on-html5-canvas), and the answer only produces a very inaccurate image, as the gradients added later are very dominant.

Does anyone have an idea how to either make the CPU calculation faster or if there's a (proper) hardware accelerated solution?

(Code doesn't need to be backward compatible)

Comment: The last 3 lines of your code look to me to be the performance killer. (even if there's a bigger one, this code is a bit fugly) Have a look at canvas pixel operations - this seems like a reasonable introduction: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas